# Riemann-Cartan Tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

> I want to compute the Riemann tensor as done in
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07878 (equation (11)):
>   $$
> R^a{}_{bcd}=\partial_c\Gamma^a{}_{bd}-\partial_d\Gamma^a{}_{bc}+\Gamma^s{}_{bd}\Gamma^a{}_{sc}-\Gamma^s{}_{bc}\Gamma^a{}_{sd}. \tag{11}
> $$

I start by the definition and using $ \nabla_b \omega_d = \partial_b\omega_d-\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{db}\omega_a$ I find:

$$ (\nabla_b\nabla_c- \nabla_c\nabla_b)\omega_d = (\partial_c\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{db}-\partial_b\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{dc}+\Gamma^f\vphantom{\Gamma}_{cb}\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{df}+\Gamma^f\vphantom{\Gamma}_{db}\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{fc}-\Gamma^f\vphantom{\Gamma}_{bc}\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{df}-\Gamma^f\vphantom{\Gamma}_{dc}\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{fb})\omega_a+(\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{bc}-\Gamma^a\vphantom{\Gamma}_{cb})\partial_a\omega_d$$

How can I find the expression of the Riemann - Cartan tensor in 11-12 from this computation? Is there another way? (I would prefer to do by this computation tough)

Comment: Your definition of the Riemann tensor in terms of the connection is incomplete in the case of non-null torsion. You should start from:
$$R_{\alpha\beta\gamma}\,^{\rho}w_{\rho}=\left[\nabla_{\alpha},\nabla_{\beta}\right]w_{\gamma}+2S_{\alpha\beta}\,^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}w_{\gamma}\,.$$
where $w_{\rho}$ is some 1-form and $S_{\alpha\beta}\,^{\rho}$ is the torsion tensor.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this definition?

Comment: I can't seem to find a reference where the expression is explicitly written. You can, however, work it out by writing the Lie derivative of a vector field along a curve in terms of the connection (where a term dependent of the torsion tensor will appear) and use that result in the first expression in the wikipedia entry [Riemann tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) (which is the definition of the Riemann tensor). It is a little laborious but quite straightforward.

Comment: It seems I can't find the formula for the lie derivative in terms of the connection, do you have one or a reference?

Comment: Don't worry, I found out a way finally to reach the result, thank you very much for your help.